# Update React state correctly

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-state

How to update react state correctly ? I have a drop down with countries and a table with country and it's cities. Based on the selected country from dropdownlist, table should show only that country and cities.

Below code filters the table data correctly for the first time. When country is changed, table doesn't show data for the selected country from **second** time.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";

import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";

import Table from "@material-ui/core/Table";
import TableBody from "@material-ui/core/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";
import TableHead from "@material-ui/core/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  button: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1)
  },
  input: {
    display: "none"
  }
}));

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    selectedCountry: "",
    countries: []
  };

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state.countries = [
      this.createData("US", "DC"),
      this.createData("UK", "London"),
      this.createData("Aus", "Canberra"),
      this.createData("US", "Newyork"),
      this.createData("UK", "Birmingham"),
      this.createData("Aus", "Sidney")
    ];
  }

  createData(country, capital) {
    return { country, capital };
  }

  handleChange(value) {
    this.setState({ selected: value });
    this.setState({
      countries: this.state.countries.filter(c => c.country === value)
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <label value="Select Country: ">Select Country: </label>
        <Select
          style={{ width: "10%" }}
          value={this.state.selected}
          onChange={event => this.handleChange(event.target.value)}
          name="country"
          displayEmpty
        >
          <MenuItem value="" disabled>
            Select a country
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="US">US</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="UK">UK</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="AUS">Aus</MenuItem>
        </Select>

        <Table>
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell align="center">Country</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="center">Capital city</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {this.state.countries.map(row => (
              <TableRow key={row.name}>
                <TableCell align="center">{row.country}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="center">{row.capital}</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here,

```
this.setState({
   countries: this.state.countries.filter(c => c.country === value)
});
```

Here you are filtering the `countries` array and storing it to the same. So when first time you filter your original `countries` array is gets changed and you only have filtered data. On next filter you are filtering data from previous result and not from original array.

You need to keep a copy of original data in a constructor,

```
constructor() {
    super();
    //This is initial state
    this.state.countries = [
      this.createData("US", "DC"),
      this.createData("UK", "London"),
      this.createData("Aus", "Canberra"),
      this.createData("US", "Newyork"),
      this.createData("UK", "Birmingham"),
      this.createData("Aus", "Sidney")
    ];

    //this is the copy of original data
    this.countries = [
      this.createData("US", "DC"),
      this.createData("UK", "London"),
      this.createData("Aus", "Canberra"),
      this.createData("US", "Newyork"),
      this.createData("UK", "Birmingham"),
      this.createData("Aus", "Sidney")
    ];
  }
```

Now you can filter over original data every time,

```
this.setState({
   countries: this.countries.filter(c => c.country === value)
});
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nddklv)

**Note:** You should use `.toLowerCase()` at the time of comparing in your `filter`. Because you have `Aus` as country in your state and `AUS` as value in your select. It is better if you compare lowerCase value,

```
this.setState({
   countries: this.countries.filter(c => c.country.toLowerCase() === value.toLowerCase())
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use const value inside the render method. The const value will every time update when there is a change in the selected country.

remove line `this.setState({
      countries: this.state.countries.filter(c => c.country === value)
    });`

and add below code

```
render() {
    const filteredCountries = this.state.countries.filter(c=> c.countries === this.state.selected);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <label value="Select Country: ">Select Country: </label>
        <Select
          style={{ width: "10%" }}
          value={this.state.selected}
          onChange={event => this.handleChange(event.target.value)}
          name="country"
          displayEmpty
        >
          <MenuItem value="" disabled>
            Select a country
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="US">US</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="UK">UK</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="AUS">Aus</MenuItem>
        </Select>

        <Table>
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell align="center">Country</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="center">Capital city</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {this.state.filteredCountries.map(row => (
              <TableRow key={row.name}>
                <TableCell align="center">{row.country}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="center">{row.capital}</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Instead of using another state for "filteredCountries", this is more efficient way to solve this problem.

Comment: Using this way, it will not print any data on first render. it will only show data when you select the option.

Comment: You mean to say, It wont work when there is not country selected? If that is the case, Ideally it should work that way for this case right?

Comment: Filtering the data is secondary part, primary goal is to show data. It is upto end user if user want to filter or not.